# c++ array assignment of multiple values

Tags: c++, arrays, programming-languages, syntax

so when you initialize an array, you can assign multiple values to it in one spot:

```
int array [] = {1,3,34,5,6}
```

but what if the array is already initialized and I want to completely replace the values of the elements in that array in one line

so

```
int array [] = {1,3,34,5,6}
array [] = {34,2,4,5,6}
```

doesn't seem to work...

is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

There is a difference between **initialization** and **assignment**. What you want to do is not initialization, but assignment. But such assignment to array is not possible in C++.

Here is what you can do:

```
#include <algorithm>

int array [] = {1,3,34,5,6};
int newarr [] = {34,2,4,5,6};
std::copy(newarr, newarr + 5, array);
```

---

However, in C++0x, you can do this:

```
std::vector<int> array = {1,3,34,5,6};
array = {34,2,4,5,6};
```

Of course, if you choose to use `std::vector` instead of raw array.

Comment: `std::copy(std::begin(newarr), std::end(newarr), std::begin(array));` would be better, wouldn't it?

Comment: @MattCruikshank: Yes. But that wasn't possible in C++03.

Comment: Better to use `std::array` instead of `std::vector` when it's fixed size.

Comment: I am looking for a pointer to the Standard about this rule. Do you know where it is?

Answer (score 10):

You have to replace the values one by one such as in a for-loop or copying another array over another such as using `memcpy(..)` or `std::copy`

e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    array[i] = newValue[i];
}
```

Take care to ensure proper bounds-checking and any other checking that needs to occur to prevent an out of bounds problem.

Answer (score 5):

I made a little template function to conveniently assign values to a raw pointer.

```cpp
template <typename T, typename U>
void set_array(T* array, U x) {
  *array = x;
}

template <typename T, typename U, typename... V>
void set_array(T* array, U x, V... y) {
  *array = x;
  set_array(array + 1, y...);
}
```

An example is:

```cpp
int main() {
  int64_t array[10] = {};
  set_array(array, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16);
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]); ++i) {
    std::cout << array[i] << ", ";
  }
}
```

...and it should print:

```
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0,
```

Comment: Seems it could be made more safe if accepting not T* but array type.

Answer (score 2):

```
const static int newvals[] = {34,2,4,5,6};

std::copy(newvals, newvals+sizeof(newvals)/sizeof(newvals[0]), array);
```