# c++ class array initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, class, variables, initialization

so I have this class in the header

```
class C{

   int b [2];

   init();

}
```

and in C.cpp I have

```
C::init(){

   bK [2] = {3,7};
}
```

whereby I try to initialize the class variable b which is an array

but then the compiler returns the error `expected ; before { token` and `expected primary expression before { token`

what did i do wrong and how do I properly initialize array class variables?

Comment: How is this different than your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732798/c-array-assignment-of-multiple-values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

End your class definition with a `;`.

```
class C {

   int b [2];

   init();

};
```

Also, you cannot initialize an array like that away from the declaration in standard C++.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in pre-C++0x C++.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't allowed by the Standard (2003). Arrays declared in class cannot be initialized.

What you can do is this:

```
C::init(){
   b[0] = 3;
   b[1] = 7;
}
```

---

In C++0x, you can do this (if you choose to use `std::vector`):

```
class C
{
   std::vector<int> b;
   void init() 
   { 
       b = {3,7}; 
   }
};
```

See online demo : http://www.ideone.com/NN5aT

Answer (score 0):

```
C::init(){

   bK [0] = 3;
   bk [1] = 7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare you class members as either public, private or protected. And also you need a return type for you init(). You also might need a semicolon at the end of your class definition, which you can't do with c++ class members.

You should use a constructor instead of your init(). That way you don't have to call init() after every time you declare an object, it will be done for you.

```
class C{
private:
   int b[2];
public:
   C();

};

C::C()
{
    b[0] = 2;
    b[1] = 3;
}
```

**Edit:** After doing some testing, I found it was buggy. This code above has no errors in it. If you want to inline initialize a whole array, it has to be done in its declaration statement.