# 'IntelliSense: expected an expression' on Assigning Value to Global Variable

Tags: c++, arrays, variables, global

Please help me, I am quite new to C++

I code this in VS 2010

I have a global variable

```
int avg[SAMPLE][3];
```

I would like to modify the value in main program by doing something like this:

```
avg[SAMPLE][3] = {
{30,96,56}, {13,114,55}, {16,118,46},{19,143,64}, {12,129,68},{13,153,69},{15,120,67}
```

};

However, the VS shows an error: IntelliSense: expected an expression

But it is okay when I declare the value directly to global variable

```
int avg[SAMPLE][3] = {
{30,96,56}, {13,114,55}, {16,118,46},{19,143,64}, {12,129,68},{13,153,69},{15,120,67}
```

};

Perhaps this is trivial, but please help me, I am new into C++, and therefore, do not have a clue about it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-assigning with an initializer list is not available in C++. C++11 adds this option to classes but not to static C arrays like your example.

What you can do is have one or more `const` global/static of the value you need and `memcpy` them when needed:

```
static const int g_avg[SAMPLE][3] = {
   {30,96,56}, {13,114,55}, {16,118,46},{19,143,64}, {12,129,68},{13,153,69},{15,120,67}
};

// usage
int avg[SAMPLE][3];
// ...
memcpy(avg, g_avg, sizeof(avg));
```

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to +1 on the answer as well :)

Comment: Ùsing `memcpy` is bad advice, since (1) it's only well defined for standard layout item types, and (2) it's low level and easy to get wrong, a bug attractor. Continuing to use raw arrays as the default choice is also bad advice, but if one does that, then `std::copy` is efficient enough, generally applicable (as opposed to `memcpy`), and far more safe to use. This question is about **C++**, not about C.

Answer (score 1):

Raw (built-in) arrays are not assignable.

However, you can use `std::array` (fixed size) or `std::vector`, which are assignable.

It's not a good idea to use global variables. It is a good idea to reserve all uppercase for macro names.

In C++11 (which is not supported by Visual Studio 2010, but you can just get a new free version like Visual Studio 2013),

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Sample { int x, y, z; };

auto main()
    -> int
{
    vector<Sample> avg =
    {
        {30,96,56}, {13,114,55}, {16,118,46},{19,143,64}, {12,129,68},{13,153,69},{15,120,67}
    };

    avg = { {1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2} };

    for( Sample const s : avg )
    {
        cout << s.x << ", " << s.y << ", " << s.z << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just of curiosity...why on earth do you prefer your main() function to be a lambda :)? Is that even guaranteed to work? I thought the compiler could mangle the names on lambdas...

Comment: @TripShock: it's not a lambda. but it's nearly the same syntax. i use one common syntax for all functions, including function templates. that's much easier as i see it. this places the function name at a fixed visual place, and the function result type at fixed place, so that it's much easier to scan the code. it's also more clean (less variation) with just one syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you used is one that can be used to initialize an array. However, in C/C++, you cannot use that same syntax to assign multiple values to the array. You will have to resort to assigning each value, use a loop, etc.

Just searched a bit more and found a possible duplicate: [c++ array assignment of multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732798/c-array-assignment-of-multiple-values)