# Array assignment of multiple values in a class: Best practice

Tags: class, c++11

**I have this array in the class and I need to assign 9*9 number matrix to it.**

```
class puzzle{

    int gme[9][9];
}
```

I know it is not possible to assign an array in c++ with the braze enclosed initialization: Mentioned in this question: [c++ array assignment of multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732798/c-array-assignment-of-multiple-values)

It is possible to use `std::copy(newgme, newgme + 3, gme);` and assign the array.

I don't want to do this because we need to assign the array `newgme` outside the class and pass this as a parameter to the member function.

`Array assignment of multiple values in a class: Which is the best practice?`

I would like to set the values to these without using `vectors`:

```
                        0,0,7   ,0,0,0    ,4,0,6,
                        8,0,0   ,4,0,0    ,1,7,0,
                        0,0,0   ,3,0,0    ,9,0,5,

                        0,0,0   ,7,0,5    ,0,0,8,
                        0,0,0   ,0,0,0    ,0,0,0,
                        4,0,0   ,2,0,8    ,0,0,0,

                        7,0,4   ,0,0,3    ,0,0,0,
                        0,5,2   ,0,0,1    ,0,0,9,
                        1,0,8   ,0,0,0    ,6,0,0
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, `std::copy` won't work because the nested array `int[9]` is not itself assignable.  Some people might advise to alias the multidimensional array as an `int[81]` but this is undefined behaviour.

Your best bet is probably to use a nested `std::array`:

```
std::array<std::array<int, 9>, 9> gme;
```

Future versions of C++ may have a multidimensional array type.

Another option is [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html), although that has dynamic extents (and therefore uses dynamic memory allocation).

Comment: I tried as you told but got this error:'array' in namespace 'std' does not name a type. I added `#include<array>` and got this error: `#error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.` This method is supported by ISO c++ 2011 standards only? And you suggest this is the best method?

Answer (score 1):

I assume `newgme` is declared this way:

```
int newgme[9][9];
```

In such a case, you can use `memcpy`:

```
void puzzle::set_gme(int newgme[9][9])
{
    memcpy(gme, newgme, sizeof(gme));
}
```

`memcpy` is a library function inherited from C; it only works on POD types, which happens to be exactly your case (explained in a great length in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4178176/509868)).