# error : expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Tags: c++, struct

I'm getting an error:

> expression must be a modifiable lvalue at line, `obj.name = ptr->name`

I have tried to make **obj** an **array type object** like so

```
 for(int j=0 ;j<1;j++)
{
obj[j].id = ptr->id;
obj[j].balance= ptr->balance;
obj[j].name = ptr->name;   //still getting error here.
obj[j].nic = ptr->nic;
}
return(obj);
}
```

but that has not worked either.

if i comment the error out and pass just three remaining values it should work but i receive garbage values after the first out put.

here is the original code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct bank
{
  int id, nic;
  float balance;
  char name[20];


};
bank search(bank* );

void main()

{

    bank data[2],mobj;
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
    cout<<"enter name: ";
    cin>>data[i].name;
    cout<<"enter id: ";
    cin>>data[i].id;
    cout<<"enter balance : ";
    cin>>data[i].balance;
    cout<<"enter nic : ";
    cin>>data[i].nic;

    }


    mobj=search(data);

    cout <<"balance of customer no. "<<mobj.balance<<endl;
    cout<<"id is" <<mobj.id<<endl;
    cout<< "nic is"<<mobj.nic<<endl;



    system("pause");
}




bank search(bank *ptr)
{   
    int id;
    cout<<"enter value you want to serch"<<endl;
    cin>>id;
    bank obj;
for(int i=0 ; i<2 ;i++)
{
    if(ptr->id == id)
    {
        break;
    }
    ptr++;
}

obj.id = ptr->id;
obj.balance= ptr->balance;
obj.name = ptr->name;    //error in this line(obj must be modifiable value)
obj.nic = ptr->nic;

return(obj);
}
```

please help as you see fit!

Comment: You can't do assignment on arrays.

Comment: In C++ you should (almost) never use plain C-style arrays. Use `std::vector` or `std::array` depending on if you want dynamic or static size, or of course `std::string` if you are dealing with strings.

Comment: You again. Just a warning: you're fast approaching an automatic question ban due to this succession of low-quality "help me plz" questions.

Comment: @MustafaMujahid: It doesn't really matter whether it's your first day or your last. Or your 4000th. You should read the Help Centre and examine existing questions to find out what posts look like here. That you haven't been here very long is not much of an excuse. What "forum"?

Comment: This question _is_ much better than your previous ones, though! My concern is that posting so many questions in quick succession strongly implies that you are not spending enough of your _own_ time on your problems. It shines through in the lack of research effort, too.

Comment: You have other errors, by the way. What happens to your search if the id is not found?

Comment: yeah i have that in mind ill just use an else statement fairly simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`obj.name` is an array of `char`. You cannot do assignments on arrays. So if you want to stick to arrays:

1. see [c++ array assignment of multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732798/c-array-assignment-of-multiple-values)
2. use `strcpy(obj.name, ptr->name);`

but I'd recommend to convert to `std::string` ... it's much easier to work with than arrays and it seems to me you plan to use `obj.name` as string. So got with the proper strings.

Answer (score 2):

Your options are:

- Have `name` as a `std::string`. Then it will work
- use `strcpy( obj.name, ptr->name );`

If your code is C++ then the first has even more advantages that when you read it in with `cin` it will automatically ensure that the buffer is big enough for what the user enters.

Try entering a name of 20 or more characters now and see what happens. You will have undefined behaviour and your program may crash.

Those are the fixes anyway.

The reason your code does not work is that an array is not assignable. It is not an `l-value`. It is the start of a fixed array of bytes. I know it is confusing because you can use `=` to initialise it thus you can do:

```
char name[20] = "Frank Smith"; // legal. This is initialisation
```

but you can't do:

```
char name[20];
name = "Frank Smith"; // error. This is attempted assignment.
```

With `std::string` it works as `string` is a class in the standard library. (Actually the class is `basic_string< char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >` but assume it is a class for now). And it has methods that know how to assign to it, stream into it, etc. and manage the memory properly.

The only time the array in your `struct` is more useful is if you want to store it to disk or send it over a connection where you need "raw" data, or where you want to interface it with "C" or a scripting language that works with `C` structs.

Answer (score 0):

obj[j].name is an array. You can't copy an array like that.