# Fill an array with incoming integers

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array `static const unsigned int numbers[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`

From an another loop I am getting integers, how do I fill my array `numbers[]` with those incoming integers instead?

Comment: Explain "fill" do you mean pushing elements? or replace the one that are already inside?

Comment: You shouldn't change it if it is `const`.

Answer (score 0):

> As you guessed, the "static" part limits it's scope to that
>   compilation unit. It also provides for static initialization. "const"
>   just tells the compiler to not let anybody modify it. This variable is
>   either put in the data or bss segment depending on the architecture,
>   and might be in memory marked read-only.

More info [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177437/what-does-const-static-mean-in-c-and-c)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I never seen assign an array in this way:

```
numbers[] = test;
```

Maybe you should study about array. 
Maybe you can use this way for copy:

```
int array [] = {1,3,34,5,6};
int newarr [] = {34,2,4,5,6};
std::copy(newarr, newarr + 5, array);
```

or just use simple loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    array[i] = newValue[i];
}
```

For more read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732798/c-array-assignment-of-multiple-values)

Moreover you declare your array as `const` that stay for *constant*, tells you something?

> [...]constants are useful for parameters which are used in the program but
>   are do not need to be changed after the program is compiled.

So I suggest to sudy about `const` too! Read [here](http://duramecho.com/ComputerInformation/WhyHowCppConst.html)